# Git repositories on network drive all showing same error when cloned: "packfile does not match index"

Tags: git, clone, pack

I've been trying to solve this for hours and I've had 0 luck. Apologies in advance, I'm fairly novice when it comes to Git.

I have a large amount of Git repositories on a network drive (R: drive). All of these repositories are clones of another repository with different changes made in each one.

For my work, I frequently need to clone 10+ of these repositories to my local machine (C: drive), so I thought I would make a batch script that would automate the process for me.

When I ran my batch script (which was essentially just 10+ `git clone R:\INSERT_REPO_HERE C:\INSERT_DIRECTORY_HERE` statements), the process took hours, but this was normal, as my connectivity to the R: drive was poor.

**The issue:**

I was looking into ways to speed up the cloning process, and had found advice to do the following:

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.SizeLimit "100m" 
git config --global pack.threads "1"
git config --global pack.window "0"
git config --global core.compression 0
git config --global core.bigfilethreshold 200K
```

So, I ran those commands on both R: and C: drive.

Now, whenever I clone *any* repo from the R: drive to my C: drive, I get the following error:

```
Cloning into 'C:\Users\games\Documents\BitBucket\Adapt topics\BU11\BU11.3\src\course\en'...
done.
error: packfile C:/Users/games/Documents/BitBucket/Adapt topics/BU11/BU11.3/src/course/en/.git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
error: packfile C:/Users/games/Documents/BitBucket/Adapt topics/BU11/BU11.3/src/course/en/.git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
error: unable to read sha1 file of project/bower.json (15bb293aca56d25d07f9372c81d6d008b41f93cc)


error: packfile C:/Users/games/Documents/BitBucket/Adapt topics/BU11/BU11.3/src/course/en/.git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
error: packfile C:/Users/games/Documents/BitBucket/Adapt topics/BU11/BU11.3/src/course/en/.git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
error: unable to read sha1 file of project/js/project.js (02dbe8ec5a71541ce175fada7e0d405359124968)


fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

I have tried `--unset`ting the global config I set, but it doesn't fix anything. As far as I can see, the repos on the R: drive still have all my files, so I haven't lost any data; but I can't seem to find a way to fix this issue, and re-creating every single repo on the R: drive would take me a very long time too.

Also, running `git fsck --full` gives this result, regardless of which repository I do it on:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack cannot be accessed
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
Checking connectivity: 369, done.
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-2105520c4dd562760badf1555e89a734a7dddfa3.pack does not match index
broken link from    tree fc7405e6041f547e5845cead57f06a38ed4b814f
              to    blob db3d21c232d266d476e028af6fe640b5447dba14
```

I'm not even entirely sure what a "pack file" even is. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
I don't know if this helps, but looking in the `.git/objects/pack` folder of each repository in the R: drive shows that the .pack file was last modified on the same day that I ran the `git config` commands:

[image: Pack last modified]

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer to my original post, I have found a workaround that's appropriate for my specific situation. Basically, I just recreated each repository.

I went into each repository and deleted the ".git" file, then ran

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'PackFix'
```

This does mean I've now **lost** all Git commit history for these repositories, but thankfully (for my specific situation), this isn't a big issue.

To anyone reading this in the future, I'd say this thread is more a warning about running `--global` commands on a network drive (especially if you don't fully understand what they'll do).

Answer (score -1):

**Never** store a Git repository on a networked or cloud-synced drive.

What, "never"?<sup>1</sup>

Yes, really, *never*.  Why not?  Because problems like the one you saw *will* occur.  Just don't do it.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Obligatory link](https://youtu.be/kBK39BKWuQg?t=60)

Comment: Well, I suppose I sorta already knew that. With that being said though, our repositories often needed to contain multiple large (1G+) video files in them, hence why we set them up the way we did, since online storage isn't cheap (or fast to upload to).

Is there really no way to just "reset" the Git repositories? I don't even mind if it means losing the commit history and just starting a fresh history from the current state, as long as it means we can pull + push + clone again.

Comment: In that case, why use Git at all? Just store the files and let the shared/cloudsync storage do its thing. The Git repository will keep getting damaged, so don't use Git.

Comment: We need to use Git because we frequently have multiple employees working on the same   repo at once, so they need an easy way to get the latest changes from everyone else.

Comment: Git is a management system, not just a simple sharing system. If you just need simple sharing, use the shared drive and rsync. If you need fancy source management, don't use the shared *drive* (disk space is cheap now...). Set up a central non-shared system and put a Git server there.